# В Тимошенко? Или в Тимошенке?

Tags: склонение

Склонение села Тимошенко. Стоит ли склонять? Как-то выглядит не очень)))....

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, склонять действительно не надо.
Но это редчайшее исключение из общего правила. Поскольку происхождение названия точно неизвестно (крымско-татарское село Озенбаш после депортации и заселения выходцами с Украины было переименовано в Тимошенко), нужно как-то выкручиваться. Происхождение нового названия достоверно неизвестно, но очень сильно напоминает фамилию. Вообще такие названия (на -ко) нехарактерны ни для Крыма, ни вообще. А вот фамилия - весьма распространена.
Поэтому, полагаю, проще подстраховаться.

(+)
Формулировка "известного лица" мне не нравится. Не дело автора решать, насколько известен Лермонтов или Репин. Тут, видимо, подразумевается, что фамилией малоизвестного/неизвестного лица населенный пункт не назовут.
По факту правило применяется без оговорок на известность лица. Что, впрочем, тоже не всем нравится. Я подсознательно готов склонять (в устой речи - точно) и Лермотово, и Репино...

(++) Судя по всему, следует добавить в отношении позиции @ЕгорСальков.
Взятая из неизвестного мне источника (предположительно - из ответа справки на "Грамоте.ру") формулировка утверждает, что сколняются некоторые названия. Разумеется, никому (Кроме Егора Салькова) в голову не придет утверждать, что этот список исчерпывающий.
Поэтому все остальные принципиально склоняемые (то есть имеющие для того грамматические формы) топонимы склоняются по общему правилу.

Всех, кто имеет другое мнение прошу назвать **прямое правило** о несклонении подобных топонимов (на -ко).

Comment: *фамилия - весьма распространена* — Учитывая 1946-й год, в первую очередь вспоминается маршал С.К. Тимошенко.

Comment: @grizzly Маршала-то я знаю. Может, конечно и так, но не хочу гадать на кофейной гуще. Справедливости ради: во-первых, не 1946-й, а 1948-й. А во-вторых, какая-либо связь не просматривается. Не помню точно, но, кажется,  из Бессарабии, откуда маршал родом, никого в Крым не переселяли... Ну и то, что такие вещи обычно хорошо известны.

Comment: Да, я поспешил с выводами. [Здесь](http://kimmeria.com/crimea_placenames/appearance/appearance_05_03.htm) сказано, что название дано в честь И.Т.Тимошенко (см. Вики). Материал подписан И. Л. Белянским, который выпустил справочник по географическим названиям Крыма в соавторстве с известным специалистом в топонимике А.В. Суперанской (сам справочник мне найти не удалось).

Comment: @grizzly Да, это больше похоже на правду. Но мне не хотелось бы продолжать этот разговор на основании материалов, опубликованных на российско-крымском портале. Я обязательно скачусь в политику и разоблачение фейков. Больная для меня тема. (+) И еще. Суперанскую вы для красного словца помянули? Такое использование известных имен не добавляет авторитетности источнику. В материале нет ссылок на тот справочник.

Comment: Зная ключевые слова несложно найти [ресурсы по вкусу](https://www.academia.edu/10251065/ТОПОНИМИКА_КРЫМА_2010_СБ_СТАТЕЙ_ПАМЯТИ_И_Л_БЕЛЯНСКОГО_Симферополь_Универсум_2011_376_с) (см. стр. 117). Это 2011 г. издания, поэтому давайте обойдёмся без политики. Суперанскую я упомянул в качестве косвенного подтверждения авторитета одного из соавторов её книг. Авторитетности я добавлял не источнику, а автору — если бы это был никому неизвестный любитель, я бы не стал на него ссылаться.

Comment: @grizzly про Суперанскую - остаюсь при своем мнении. Такое "косвенное" подтверждение источнику авторитетности не добавлячет. А авторитетность автора в отрыве от источника - это вообще нонсенс.

Comment: Насчет источника "по вкусу". У меня нет вкуча к источникам, запрашивающим для выгрузки мои личные данные.

Comment: У меня вкусы не менее требовательные, наверное. Но там же ничего не нужно скачивать; я не поленился указать номер страницы — просто нужно прокрутить вниз. Про Суперанскую каждый из нас остался при своём мнении, вряд ли здесь уместно будет развивать эту тему.

Comment: @grizzly А о чем тогда разговор-то? Ну прокрутил. Ваше уточнение про происхождение названия я принял с благодарностью. Что еще-то я должен узнать в этом тексте? Знаете, я всегда вспоминаю восточную мудрость: "Ты сказал - я поверил. Ты повторил - я усомнился. Ты стал настаивать - я понял, что ты врешь". Вы этого добиваетесь?

Comment: *Наша пiсня гарна знову.* Ладно, давайте по-порядку. Вы отказались обсуждать первый ресурс по политическим мотивам. Я нашёл Вам то же на другом ресурсе (я уже с пониманием отношусь к проблемам других участником в пользовании поисковиками), безупречном с точки зрения политики. Вы пожаловались на новый ресурс по другим мотивам, и тогда я просто объяснил Вам, что эти мотивы вообще нерелевантны. Фу-х, если ещё что-то не понятно или прозвучало излишне оскорбительно для Вас, обратитесь к модераторам, пусть они всё это удаляют.

Comment: @grizzly Вы сайчас переврали всё, что могли. Во-первых, я не отказывался обсуждать ресурс.  Я просто попросил вас не продолжать этот разговор на больную для меня тему. Во-вторых, обсуждать какой-то ресурс - вообще занятие не для ресурса нашего. В-третьих, я вас не просил что-то искать, но коли вы нашли "для иеня", объясните, что мне оттуда надо? И пожалейте уже меня, пишите по делу, если есть что реально добавить в ответ. Иначе мне действительно придется позвать модератора. даже ценой собственного бана.

Comment: Короче, есть предложение. Можете считать его ультиматумом. Или вы внятно и содержательно формулируете то, что вы хотите мне доказать - или буду считать ваше творчество троллингом.

Answer (score 0):

> В письменной речи, в соответствии с действующими грамматическими
> правилами, географические названия на *-ов(о), -ёв(о), -ев(о), -ин(о),
> -ын(о)* склоняются: *В небе над Тушином (газ.); Речь идет об аэропорте в Шереметьеве (газ.).*

Несклоняемость географических наименований нормальна в следующих случаях:

> ...Если населенный пункт назван собственным именем известного лица:
> *около Репино* (назв. поселка под Ленинградом), *недалеко от Лермонтово* (назв. небольшого города около Пензы).

Выбирайте, какая/какое именно у Вас Тимошенко - прославленное или так себе.

См.: http://rusgram.narod.ru/1216-1231.html#1220)

Comment: Откуда он знает-то?